# PlayFramework - Executing query in DBAction

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, slick-2.0

I'm using Play 2.3.8 and Slick 2.1.0 and according to the docs, I should be able to execute queries in my controller actions like this:

```
val customers = TableQuery[Customers]

def index = DBAction { implicit request =>
  val result = Json.toJson(customers.list)
  Ok(result)
}
```

However, when I try this I get an error - no implicit session in scope. I can get around it by doing this:

```
val customers = TableQuery[Customers]

def index = DBAction { implicit request => 
  implicit val session = request.dbSession
  val result = Json.toJson(customers.list)
  Ok(result)
}
```

Is this what's required or is there a simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the play-slick plugin have you used?

Comment: `import request.dbSession` would do it too.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I'm using 0.8.1

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that implicit using this imports (PoC):

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._

...

object Products extends Controller {

  def all = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(products.list))
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using Play 2.3.7 and for Slick this library dependency:
`"com.typesafe.play"   %%  "play-slick"             % "0.8.1"`